# Is there an Exit method to exit a nested procedure and its owner procedure?

Tags: delphi, control-flow

Is there a method one could call to Exit from inside a nested procedure which will also exit the owner/parent procedure?

```
procedure OwnerProc;

    procedure NestedProc;
    begin
      // Do some code here

      EXIT_ALL; {Call a method which will exit NestedProc and OwnerProc}
    end;

begin
  NestedProc;
end;
```

Comment: You want to learn about *Exceptions*.

Comment: Or simply change it from a Procedure to a Function and return a Boolean. you can then check if the result was false and exit the main procedure

Comment: If I take EXIT_ALL literally, a `Halt;` would do the job ;) - Warning : use only in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: @mjn :-) I suppose the "All" has to be replaced by "ThisOneAndParent"

Comment: In Delphi we use silent exception EAbort by calling the method Abort.

Comment: @ZENsan Abort is silent within VCL applications [only](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Silent_Exceptions). But I would prefer exceptions over boolean return values.

Comment: @mjn Performance could be a problem with exceptions, there are scenarios where they are expensive. EAbort is silent everywhere if you catch it, and in the usage here you'd catch it in the outer function.

Comment: @mjn: Abort is in System.SysUtils. It is not VCL. VCL just handles it in a special way.

Comment: @ZENSan this exactly what I mean. It is silent within VCL applications only, because VCL treats it differently.

Comment: Do you realize what `Exit` is not a method or real procedure, but an intrinsic language construct like `Break` or `Continue`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a method one could call to Exit from inside a nested procedure which will also exit the owner/parent procedure?

No there is not.

You could raise an exception, and catch it in the outer function. But personally I would regard that as rather ugly. Perhaps cleaner is to return a boolean from the inner function and then `exit` if the inner function returns `False`.

Comment: Ah beat me to it :-)

Comment: Thanks David. I do use the boolean results way but was hoping that there might be an existing method to do an ExitAll.